# Magento - Properly setting up the business structure (Websites, Stores, Store View)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Good afternoon. I have reviewed many blogs and forums, and watched several youtube instructional videos on this but still do not know if what I want to do is possible and if so how to do it. (This is for a new project of a small nonprofit organization).

What I am looking to do (using non-magento definitions) is:
1) Have many different websites, which will be set up as subdomains, that are essentially structured the same but have different logos.
2) Have one central inventory that is accessible to all of the different websites.
3) Those websites, while sharing an inventory, do not have to have the same catalog. Some items may be hidden from one website but visible on another. 
4) Each website needs to be able to have its own promotions and shipping configurations and prices
5) All websites should share user data
6) I should be able to run reports at a website level as well as all websites combined.
7) I want to DISABLE open registration so that users can only exists if I or an authorized user creates the account for them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
J

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Can you revise your question to be a more specific as to what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: Since you question is not about a specific programming issue, but about general Magento setup/configuration maybe http://magento.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is definitely possible, but will require a bit of time and effort configuring your Magento instance. I have set up something similar and will quickly go through your points:

1) I have multiple websites but run each one on the same domain in a separate sub folder. You can use separate sub domains if you prefer this approach, and you will need to set up the sub domains to point to the same location and have your web server (apache/nginx) automatically set some environment variables (ie website name / store name) based on the sub domain (check the index.php to see what these are) so that Magento knows which store to display.  Re different logos this is already supported per site.

2) The inventory is already centralized and you can specify under websites which site you want the product to be available for.

3) After you have made the products available for each site you can individually enable/disable each product per site.

4) You can have a default price per product when you add it, then override it per site, this is no problem. I am sure promotions can be made site specific but I don't use this functionality much. Shipping can also be made site specific and for my case I rolled my own shipping extension, there are plenty of examples on the net.

5) Sharing user data is just a setting you can turn on.

6) Yes I think you should be ok here as well, and in the worst case you can always create your own custom reports (assuming you are not using Magento Go).

7) Yes this is possible, you can either use an extension or even just update your theme so you only provide login functionality.